# ogr2ogr / GDAL remove features in FileGDB while in use by ArcGIS Server map service

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm using ogr2ogr to pull features out of Oracle and put them into a File GeoDatabase. The FGDB is being used by an active ArcGIS Server map service. This is all done for performance / reducing DB load. The DB data is refreshed nightly and then the ogr2ogr process runs so I don't worry about stale FGDB records.

The data can both grow and shrink overnight during the update so I need my FGDB refresh to both remove and add features.

I know this is possible if I use ogr2ogr's `-overwrite` option, e.g.

```
ogr2ogr --config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES -f "FileGDB" <path to>.gdb OCI:user/pass@SID -overwrite -nlt LINESTRING -a_srs EPSG:4326 -nln layer_name -sql "select * from src_table"
```

But `-overwrite` fails if I don't first stop the ArcGIS Server map service.

I can use `-update -append` to update FGDB records while the service is running but this is 'additive' - records are added but nothing is removed.

```
ogr2ogr --config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES -f "FileGDB" <path to>.gdb OCI:user/pass@SID -update -append -nlt POINT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -nln layer_name -sql "select * from src_table"
```

I'm looking for a way to either

1. Truncate the FGDB layer without removing it prior to an `-update -append` or
2. Change my ogr2ogr command to remove features not pulled from Oracle

I also saw <strike>[this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17777/2788)</strike> [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/) on programmatically stopping / starting AGS map services but option 1 or 2 is my preference as I want an approach that doesn't require authentication / tokens over HTTP. If necessary I can bring in Python and perhaps the arcpy module.

Any input on GDAL / ogr2ogr parameters I haven't seen yet that might help would be much appreciated (or alternative approaches of course).

Comment: No idea if this will work, but have you tried issuing a TRUNCATE TABLE <table> or DELETE * FROM <table> SQL statement through the FGDB driver? See the "SQL support" note on the FGDB driver page: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html

Comment: @blah238 I really like the idea but I don't understand how to send SQL to the FileGDB driver. The link isn't exhaustive. The best I can come up with is `ogr2ogr -dialect FileGDB <path to>.gdb -sql "delete from table"` but so far no joy

Comment: @blah238 Amazing! this worked: `ogrinfo -dialect FileGDB -sql "delete from table_name" <path to>.gdb` I got errors trying to use `truncate table table_name` and `truncate table_name`. Do you want to add your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: Great to hear! Done.

Comment: So you can delete the records and reinsert them _while the service is running against the file geodatabase_?

Comment: @ChadCooper that's what I was doing today and didn't see any issues. I checked the AGS log to be sure but nothing in there. I had my browser application periodically requesting maps from the service too. I think the only restriction is that you can't change the schema (including dropping and recreating the layer) while the service is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to issue SQL statements to the FileGDB driver, e.g.:

`ogrinfo -dialect FileGDB -sql "delete from <table_name>"`

See the "SQL support" note on the FGDB driver page: http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html