# Is it possible to run an arcpy execute SQL method without connecting to any database or server?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcpy, sql, spatial-database

I want to simply process a layer by writing a tool script in a toolbox without having to connect any database, so I think I may have to set up a workspace environment in ArcMap, but I'm not sure if I need to do anything else.

Essentially I want to find a Python version of the ArcObjects [`IWorkspace.ExecuteSQL` method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ExecuteSQL_Method/002500000mrv000000/).

Comment: i'm not that clear what you're asking for, but... have you reviewed the doc for [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ArcSDESQLExecute/000v00000057000000/) ? Edit: also see [GP Considerations for working with SDE](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/for_ArcSDE_data/01m100000007000000/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file geodatabases, I do not think this is possible through arcpy, but it is using GDAL/OGR: [ogr2ogr / GDAL remove features in FileGDB while in use by ArcGIS Server map service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42492/ogr2ogr-gdal-remove-features-in-filegdb-while-in-use-by-arcgis-server-map-serv/42504#42504)