# Problems with 'layer exists ' while running ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

I run command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=regional host=localhost user=*** password=***" Hsp_09_13.MIF -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -overwrite -nln postcode_sector_boundaries
```

And I have error:

> ERROR 1: Layer postcode_sector_boundaries already exists, CreateLayer
>   failed. Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.

So I run this command then:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=regional host=localhost user=*** password=***" Hsp_09_13.MIF -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco OVERWRITE=YES -overwrite -nln postcode_sector_boundaries
```

and got error:

> ERROR 1: CREATE TABLE "public"."postcode_sector_boundaries" ( OGC_FID
>   SERIAL, PRIMARY KEY (OGC_FID) ) ERROR:  relation
>   "postcode_sector_boundaries" already exists

So I remove table `postcode_sector_boundaries` and run once more last command and got:

> ERROR 1: 'CREATE INDEX "postcode_sector_boundaries_geom_idx" ON
>   "public"."postcode_sector_boundaries" USING GIST ("wkb_geometry")'
>   failed for layer postcode_sector_boundaries, index creation has
>   failed.

`postcode_sector_boundaries_geom_idx` is unique key so I think that maybe my data are broken. I would like that ogr2ogr create table without that index but I can not find where definition for this create query can be. Any one knows? Or maybe there is another solution for my problem?

**edit:**

Ok, I know what was the problem - it was because there were some other tables using values from one I wanted recreate.

Comment: So, you are trying to update/overwrite an existing PostGIS table using ogr?

Comment: Yes. It works for other tables with other data but not for this table.

Comment: I've always used the -update and -overwrite switches like:  ogr2ogr -update -overwrite -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=regional host=localhost user=*** password=***" Hsp_09_13.MIF -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -nln postcode_sector_boundaries

Comment: Adding `-update` does not help. I still have `ERROR 1: Layer postcode_sector_boundaries already exists, CreateLayer failed.
`

Comment: You have both the ogr2ogr option -overwrite and driver layer creation option -lco overwrite=yes. Try to remove the ogr2ogr overwrite.

Comment: It does not help @user30184

Comment: Ok, I know what was the problem - it was because there were some other tables using values from one I wanted recreate.

Comment: Did you had some views or triggers?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned before it was because of some other sources which were using this table.

Comment: @nospor This is the reason I use the "append" and "truncate" method, to avoid problems with depending views. I don't know why it does nothing in your case.

Comment: @thibautg I checked/run your code few times to make sure and each time no data were updated. Maybe some specific case

Comment: Fortunately you found another solution. Maybe there is an error in my command. Here's a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188078/use-ogr2ogr-to-delete-content-of-table-and-load-new-data-from-shapefile

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with `-append` (to avoid recreating the table) and `--config OGR_TRUNCATE YES` (to truncate/empty the table before uploading new data)

```
ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=regional host=localhost user=*** password=***" Hsp_09_13.MIF -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -nln postcode_sector_boundaries --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES
```

(not tested with the above command but I use it regularly with other layers)

Comment: Your code do not throw any error but also do not update any data