# Programmatically stop and start ArcGIS Server map services using Python in ArcGIS 10.5?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, map-service

In his [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17777/142109) to [Starting and stopping ArcGIS Server map services using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17639) @Jeff Berry posted how can we can programmatically stop and start ArcGIS Server 10.0 map services using Python.

How do I stop services in ArcGIS 10.5?

I couldn't find AGSSOM there.